# Read one worksheet from Excel workbook in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, xls

I have a perl script read Excel file and parse using a perl module "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple; what I want is my script to read only one tab instead of reading all tabs on the spread sheet. here what looks like the portion of the script.

```
# ### Use a Spreadsheet CPAN module for parsing Excel spreadsheet

require Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple;
my $xls = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple->read('/opt/test.xls');

$Output_Circuit_file      = "/opt/result.text";

############################################################################
$err_idx = 0;
$out_idx = 0;
@date_var = localtime;

$date = sprintf("%02d",($date_var[4] + 1)) . '/' . sprintf("%02d",$date_var[3]) . '/' . ($date_var[5] + 1900);

## ############# 

foreach my $sheet ($xls->sheets) {
   while ($sheet->has_data) {
       my @words = $sheet ->next_row;
       $ctr++;
```

anyone can help, where I can modify to read my script read only tab "A" and ignore everything else.

Comment: What do you mean by "tab"? Worksheet? If so, just don't iterate through all of them, but select the one you are interested in

Comment: sorry yes I mean work sheet. I have removed foreach my $sheet ($xls->sheets) { to -> @sheets = $xls->sheets;
 $sheet = $sheets[0]; but now the script didn't read. any idea! thanks for your time again!!

Comment: are you using "my" to declare the variables? If not, it'll fail in use strict. Post the error you got if you need more

Comment: I an using "my"..the weird part is there is no error produce when I run the script it's just blank even though the script run. so are you agree with Keveman code. should be something else cause the problem?

Comment: I think there's a deeper issue, and you may want to drop using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple, and use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel directly. When I looked at the code for Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple, it relies on undocumented internal properties. They may have been supported once, but Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple was last updated five years ago, but Spreadsheet::ParseExcel is actively maintained. The difference is in the MaxRow property, which if missing, would return no data. Spreadsheet::ParseExcel isn't much more complex, and it's the one I've used reliably.

Comment: ok, I have add module "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel" but I think I am lost.do you think the my code above can be easily convert to work with ParseExcel" or has to be re-written the whole code.I have very new to perl? thanks much!

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you, but the synopsis example for Spreadsheet::ParseExcel does almost exactly what you need. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following lines and read specific worksheet name

```
   $sheetname= $sheet->{sheet}->{Name}; 
   if ($sheetname !~ 'Test') { next; }
```

Thanks all for your effort to help me!!

Answer (score 3):

`foreach my $sheet ($xls->sheets)` this loop is causing you to read all sheets (worksheets), which is another word for the tabs in excel. Just read the first of the `$xls->sheets` and you've got it

```
@sheets = $xls->sheets;
$sheet = $sheets[0];
if($sheet->has_data) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: First thanks much!! I have change my script as you told me but now didn't read anything from my spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for your time I have added the following line on current code and it's working just fine.                                  $sheetname= $sheet->{sheet}->{Name}; # Sheet Name
       if ($sheetname !~ 'Test') { next; }